# What typedef does here?

Tags: c++, typedef

I know that typedef kind of allows you to give an alias to a type, but what is happening in the main function?

```
const int LOTTERY_SIZE = 5;
typedef int LotteryNumbers[LOTTERY_SIZE];
```

Since LotteryNumbers is an array of int, is lottery and user also an array of int?

```
int main(){
    LotteryNumbers lottery, user;
}
```

Comment: I also wanted to ask whether user and lottery would have the size of LOTTERY_SIZE.

Comment: `typedef` is used to define a type. Hence "type def".  Anything that is of type "LotteryNumbers" will actually be an array of int, with length 5

Comment: Maybe `LOTTERY_SIZE * sizeof(int)` bytes.

Comment: Maybe `using` syntax would be clearer: `using LotteryNumbers = int[LOTTERY_SIZE];`

Answer (score 0):

The code declares both `lottery` and `user` as variables whose type is `LotteryNumbers`, which has been defined as another name for "array of `int` of length 5".

It's equivalent to writing

```
int main(){
    int lottery[5];
    int user[5];
}
```

Comment: This is non-obvious to people new to C++ though, as the `[5]` part somehow magically jumps from the left-side of the declaration over to the right-side of the declaration, which wouldn't happen if they used a `#define` instead of a `typedef` (or even a C-style typedef for a pointer type)